# IOS 7 no longer responds to uitableview within uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have the following code that encloses a `UITableView` within a `UITableCell`, so basically it's a table within a table.  This works fine in `iOS6` and below, but in `iOS7` I can't scroll the secondary view or press into it.

Basically it shows fine as per the code below, but all touches are sent to the main table, not to the table inside the cell.

Previously it would allow both to scroll.

Here is the code that loads the second table.  tableViewCellWithTableView class is just a tablecell class and contains the `didselectrowatindex` path etc for the second table.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
tableViewCellWithTableView.data = myData;
tableViewCellWithTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[tableViewCellWithTableView setBackgroundView: nil];
tableViewCellWithTableView.tableViewInsideCell.allowsSelection = YES;
tableViewCellWithTableView.tableViewInsideCell.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
tableViewCellWithTableView.tableViewInsideCell.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:tableViewCellWithTableView];
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: In which method are you doing this?

Comment: It doesn't work, because it's bad design. It was an error that it worked on iOS6. Maybe A collection view is more suitable for your design.